Compatibility of Gradle and Flutter versions
I developed an application on my old Windows computer. A year later, I'm trying to run it on a Mac and I can't solve the problem.
Here are the errors I've encountered:
Launching lib/main.dart on Mi 9T Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/skv/Apps/Apps/australia/android/build.gradle' line: 51

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'flutterVersionCode' for DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=34, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=com.semenov.australia, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=[], buildConfigFields={}, resValues={}, proguardFiles=[], consumerProguardFiles=[], manifestPlaceholders={}, wearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/skv/Apps/Apps/australia/android/build.gradle' line: 51

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'flutterVersionCode' for DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=34, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=com.semenov.australia, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=[], buildConfigFields={}, resValues={}, proguardFiles=[], consumerProguardFiles=[], manifestPlaceholders={}, wearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 748ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here's my build.gradle file code:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // Указываем версию плагина google-services
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

// Применяем плагины с помощью блока plugins
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' // Указываем версию плагина здесь
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

//tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34 // Ваша версия SDK, если отличается, укажите здесь
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.semenov.australia"
        minSdkVersion 16 // Минимальная поддерживаемая версия Android
        targetSdkVersion 34 // Ваша версия SDK, если отличается, укажите здесь
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Конфигурация для релизной сборки
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    // Подключение Kotlin
    kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines 'enable'
        }
    }

    // Настройка сборки и плагинов
    buildFeatures {
        // Использование ViewBinding
        viewBinding true
    }

    // Подключение дополнительных зависимостей и настроек
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

I tried to set the correct versions everywhere and update everything.

Starting from Flutter 3.16, projects created with flutter create now utilize the Plugin DSL for applying Gradle plugins. If your project was created with a version of Flutter before 3.16, you'll need to perform the migration manually. Instructions for migration are available in the error message you received: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply. Alternatively, you can use a Flutter version earlier than 3.16: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive

How can I downgrade the Flutter version?

You can downgrade Flutter by running the command: flutter downgrade <version>. After that, run flutter doctor to check your development environment and ensure all necessary tools are correctly installed and configured.
